# Как вычислить проценты в C#

Tags: c#

```
        private int Calculate(int x, int y, Operation operation) {
            switch (operation) {
                case Operation.PLUS:
                    return x + y;
                case Operation.MINUS:
                    return x - y;
                case Operation.DIVIDE:
                    return x / y;
                case Operation.MULTIPLY:
                    return x * y;
                case Operation.PERCENT:
                    double number = x;
                    double percent = y;
                    double result = number * (percent / 100);
                    return (int)Math.Round(result);
                case Operation.ERROR:
                    return -1;
            }
            return -2;
        }
```

Предоставляю код, который вычисляет проценты, со всем остальным проблем нет. Для примера, вводимое число 500, проценты - 50. И вместо числа 250 выходит 25000. Не могу понять в чём проблема

Comment: Не воспроизводится             int x = 100, y = 5;
            double number = x;
            double percent = y;
            double result = number * (percent / 100);
            int pp = (int)Math.Round(result);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все  срабатывает как надо:

```
int x = 500;
int y = 50;
Console.WriteLine(System.Math.Round((double)(x * y / 100)));
```